# backup manager not working

Tags: android, backup, sharedpreferences

ok. I read docs: [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/backupapi.html) and couldn't backup my preferences anyway. My code:
AndroidManifest:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:backupAgent="TheBackupAgent" android:restoreAnyVersion="true">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key" android:value="AEdPqrEAAAAIGyGIg_B8K6KrtT06kRX_YljuwtOxzKYHBZ_H0A" />
</application>
```

my main activity:

```
package com.settings.backup.casper.backupsettings;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
private EditText txtContainer;
private Button btnSave;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    BackupManager bm = new BackupManager(this);
    bm.dataChanged();
    bm.requestRestore(new RestoreObserver() {
        @Override
        public void restoreStarting(int numPackages) {
            super.restoreStarting(numPackages);
        }
    });

    txtContainer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPreferences);
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(TheBackupAgent.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    txtContainer.setText(preferences.getString("prf", ""));

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(TheBackupAgent.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("prf", txtContainer.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
            TheBackupAgent.requestBackup(getBaseContext());
        }
    });
}
}
```

my implements of BackupAgentHelper:

```
package com.settings.backup.casper.backupsettings;

 public class TheBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {
// The name of the SharedPreferences file
static final String PREFS_NAME = "myprefs";
// A key to uniquely identify the set of backup data
static final String PREFS_BACKUP_KEY = "myprefs";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, PREFS_NAME);
    addHelper(PREFS_BACKUP_KEY, helper);
    Log.d("Test", "Adding backupagent...");
}

@Override
public void onRestore(BackupDataInput data, int appVersionCode, ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {
    super.onRestore(data, appVersionCode, newState);
}

@Override
public void onBackup(ParcelFileDescriptor oldState, BackupDataOutput data, ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {
    super.onBackup(oldState, data, newState);
}

public static void requestBackup(Context context) {
    BackupManager bm = new BackupManager(context);
    bm.dataChanged();
 }
}
```

I know that android not backpacking data immediately after call dataChanged(); that's why I used adb shell as at example on android.dev, but it's not restore when I reinstall application. In phone options I enable backup. I tried on 3 different phones this code. Are anyone know why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
bm.requestRestore(new RestoreObserver() {
        @Override
        public void restoreStarting(int numPackages) {
            super.restoreStarting(numPackages);
        }
    });
```

and `bm.dataChanged();` in `onCreate()` is not necessary.